# error 1119:access of possibly undefined property value through a reference with a static type fl.controls:label

Tags: flash, audio, flash-cs4

i am a bit new to flash.i am using flash cs4.right now i am making an mp3 player with start stop and volume.but there is an error in volume slider.

```
sTransform.volume = sldVolume.value;
```

this is the source

> error is 1119:access of possibly undefined property value through a reference with a static type fl.controls:label.

Answer (score 0):

With `fl.controls`, you should listen for change events.

```
import fl.controls.Slider; 
import fl.events.SliderEvent; 
import fl.controls.Label; 

sldVolume.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, changeHandler); 

function changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void { 
    sTransform.volume  = event.value;   
}
```

[Use the Slider component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa1.html)